Colors are flickering on android 11 with jetpack-compose
I am using Jetpack Compose in my app and have a problem with disappearing colours mainly for text on Xiaomi Redmi Android 11 (API 30).
This is how the app starts and the second picture is how the app looks like when I click on the button and return to this screen.

I tried to define colours everywhere but it still starts with white text colors...
@Composable
fun TinyCenterText(text: String) {
    Text(
        color = Color.Black,
        text = text,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontSize = 12.sp
    )
}

I also setup the default colors in the XML but it is not fixing my issue...
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MobileSDK" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>

    </style>
</resources>

=== UPDATE
this is MainActivity i have navigator. i dont sepecify any color or theme here
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...
        setContent {
            Scaffold(
                topBar = {
                TopAppBar(...)
                }
        ){ innerPadding ->
                NavHost(navController, startDestination = NavigationRoutes.MAIN.route) {
                    composable(NavigationRoutes.MAIN.route) {
                        screenName = "Main Screen"

                        resetData()

                        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                            MainScreen(navController)
                        }
                    }
                    composable(NavigationRoutes.SPACE.route) {
                        screenName = "Space Screen"

                        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                            SpaceScreen(navController)
                        }
                    }
...
}

...

And here is main screen
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavController) {
//... a lot of functions for data fetching and data manipulation nothing related to ui/theme 
...
    MainFragmentView(
        space = activeSpace,
        transaction = activeTransaction,
        theme = activeTheme,
        latestActiveTransaction = latestActiveTransaction,
        sdkResult = paymentResult,
        onChangeSpace = { navController.navigate(NavigationRoutes.SPACE.route) },
        onChangeTransaction = { navController.navigate(NavigationRoutes.TRANSACTION.route) },
        onChangeTheme = { isLight -> navController.navigate("${NavigationRoutes.THEME.route}/${isLight}") },
        onCreateTransaction = ::createTransaction,
        onPay = ::onPay,
        isLoading = isTransactionLoading,
        showPayDialog = showPayDialog,
        logText = logText
    )





Can you share the theme composable your content is wrapped in? Also, your Text should ideally already be using the appropriate content colour set from the relevant LocalContentColor composition local.

@Edric I updated the question ... meanwhile I'll check LocalContentColor...

when I use LocalContentColor for changing colors etc it works but after I leave the first activity and go back ... it has the same behaviour as my current app ... :(
